# Weird type mismatch error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting a strange type mismatch error in Eclipse which says

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyLinkedList.Node<Type> to MyLinkedList.Node<Type>
```

Both from and to are same. Still Type mismatch ? :(

Code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;


public class MyLinkedList<Type> implements Iterable<Type> {

private Node<Type> head;

// default contructor initializes the null list
public MyLinkedList(){
    head = null;
}

// Static Inner Node Class
private static class Node<Type>{
    private Type data;
    private Node<Type> next;

    public Node(Type dataValue, Node<Type> nextNode){
        this.data = dataValue;
        this.next = nextNode;
    }
}

@Override
public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private class LinkedListIterator<Type>{
    private Node<Type> nextNode;
    public LinkedListIterator(){
///////////////////////////////// ERROR ///////////////////////////
            nextNode = head;
    }
    }
}
```

error goes away if I apply this cast:

```
nextNode = (Node<Type>) head;
```

Comment: You have a class named `Type`?

Comment: SHow us the actual code please. Generics are tricky, so the error is hard to tell without the code.

Comment: your `Type` class references are different. You have a `Type` in one package and a separate `Type` class in another.

Comment: There might be more than one class named `Type`, but located in different packages. The error message sadly doesn't show the package names. Hover in Eclipse over the types, and make sure they really are of the same type.

Comment: added the code. I just have one class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-static inner class LinkedListIterator defines a new generic type `Type` in your code. But it would actually inherit the generic type from its outer class `MyLinkedList`.
Just change the class definition of the iterator to

```
private class LinkedListIterator{
```

and then it should work.

Only static inner classes do not inherit the generic type, so the generic class definition of `Node` is correct.